# Docker Replicas while debugging with Visual Studio not working as expected

Tags: docker, visual-studio, debugging, docker-compose

I am debugging a solution that uses docker containers. Its a Visual Studio solution making use of docker-compose to spin up all the required containers.

When spinning up one of each container it works 100%, but the solution is load balanced and I am trying to debug some functionality while there are more than one instance running.

Using docker-compose you can specify replicas and then it will start up more than one instance of that container:

```html
consoledemo:
  image: index.docker.io/dustyroberts/consoledemo:latest
  environment: 
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
  networks:
    - private_network
  deploy:
    replicas: 10
```

However, while debugging with Visual Studio Community it causes an error

`One or more container names used by this project is already in use. Retrying 'docker-compose up' with non-conflicting container names.`

Here is the docker-compose section when debugging the app

```html
  consoledemo:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}consoledemo
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local
    networks:
      - private_network
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
```

Is it even possible to debug multiple instances of a containerized project using Visual Studio? If so, could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm upvoting this post because I've exaclty the same issue... What's your Docker Compose version ?

Comment: I've updated to 3.8, i think originally it was 3.7

Comment: I recall from experience with another IDE that container launches were quite modified (e.g. added port forwarding to allow debugger to work), might be the case with container name as well. I bet you can overcome this with a bit of copy-paste and this [yaml feature](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#using-extensions-as-fragments) instead of replicas.

Comment: The only work-around I have found thus far is to duplicate the service in my docker compose file and 'specifying' a name for each of the two containers.

This way I can load balance between the two using traefik.

But, this still does not answer my question though, cause one would think you could make use of the 'replicas' property that docker-compose provides.

For the console example i gave above you don't need traefik as it will run anyway and hit a breakpoint from any of the containers.

Comment: Seems visual studio automatically sets the docker container_name in a generated compose file you will find in obj/, so if you can figure out a way to use a script + environment variable you may be able to generate names for replicas, otherwise I guess it's just not a feature considered in visual studio.

Comment: This has been added to the backlog: https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/359